# Вывод  информации в футере

Tags: html, css

Что-то конкретно затупил. Как вывести лого в одну строку с nav, который прописан в футере. Нужно создавать отдельный ди для лого? Свойство `float: left` для лого задал.

Скрин на данный момент :

[image: img1]

Html:

```
<footer>  
    <nav>
        <ul>            
            <li><a class="nav" href="#header">В основном</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav" href="/about/"> Подробнее<a></li>
            <li><a class="nav" href="/blog/">Рекорды</a></li>
            <li><a class="vk" href="/blog/"></a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>

     <div class="logo">
     <img src="images/logo.png" width="45" height="39">
     </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
bottom: 0;
height: 60px;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
    }

logo { 
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Код покажите. Мы должны догадаться о структуре?

Comment: Дописал в вопрос

Comment: отредактируй вопрос а то на код не удобно смотреть

Comment: попробуй добавь display:inline; ко всем элементам
footer { display:inline; bottom: 0; height: 60px; position: absolute; width: 100%; }
logo { display:inline; }
nav {display:inline;}

Answer (score 1):

Вот, взгляните, надеюсь поможет - http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/rR4Eh/5/

Код, немного сумбурный, но смысл передает.